# cannot do playback in iMacro: element not found

Tags: ui-testing

Excuse me, I have tried to use iMacro in FireFox to do playback.

However, it seems that during the playback, it try to click a button before the page finish loading such that the playback stop and iMacro complains that the element (i.e. the button )cannot be found.

I have encountered similar problem in Selenium and have used "clickAndWait" command to solve such kind of problem in Selenium.

May I ask in iMacro, does it also have command such as the "clickAndWait" in selenium for us to prevent the problem?

Or should we use any other method to deal with it in iMacro?

THank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
WAIT SECONDS=x
```